# How to set mobile phones display width that scales automatically?

Tags: css, image, mobile, squarespace

What I'm trying to say is:
I'm using squarespace for my website and it's all super cool and super easy to use for a novice like me but, I need to put some css for minor things, especially for the mobile look, because in squarespace 7.1 now you can't edit just the mobile view, but all together necessarily.
So, in specific, I want to enlarge a photo so that it will take all of the width of the screen on my phone.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 620px) { #block-6735a6ae2178770cbb51 {aspect-ratio:9/20; margin-top:250px; margin-bottom:200px;padding:0px}

#block-6735a6ae2178770cbb51 .img-block-wrapper{aspect-ratio:9/16}

#block-6735a6ae2178770cbb51 .sqs-image-shape-container-element{aspect-ratio:9/16; width:400px; height:320px;}

#block-6735a6ae2178770cbb51 img{object-fit:cover; object-position:-80px} }
```

So the width and the height are the ones changing the dimensions of the rectangle where the photo fits in.
My question is. On my phone it fits heavenly, but maybe because the width is the same as the one of my screen, would it be the same on another screen or would it mess it all up and the photo will go too out or too in on the screen? Will it resize automatically on another phone to fit its screen or will it stay the same? In second case is there a way to make it scale automatically based on what screen resolution is viewing the photo?

Comment: Please show relevant HTML. I am suspicious of those px values in a responsive context. And have you tried different devices in your browser dev tools?

Comment: Hi! No, I haven't tried it yet on ohter devices, and for what concerns HTMl what d oyou mean? inspecting the image and copying and pasting what appears on the right?

Comment: What if i put width % instead of width px? will it take the percentage of the screen? Or the percentage of what?

Comment: Sorry if maybe I'm making stupid questions, but as I said, I'm really new in these things and I'm discovering the basics now, so maybe something so simple becomes something very difficult for me

Comment: Yur browser will have a dev tools facility, which I guess you have already used to find the CSS you show, it should have a facility to emulate different devices and/or different viewport dimensions. Use that to test whether your image is filling full width. Also use it to find the relevant HTML.

Comment: Alright, first of all thank you for letting me know about the dev tool, yes I used it before to see the HTML on my page but I didn't know it was called so and I found out a lot of more features it has, like the one for viewing websites as I am on an actual phone, and that helped a lot because it seems to be "responsive" with 410px of width. I mean, it's not responsive, but even for the larger phones it seems to work as I wished, so I would say I'm quite satisfied, even if it doesn't adapt to every screen. Anyway, I'll link you the HTML for that photo

Comment: <div class="sqs-block image-block sqs-block-image sqs-text-ready" data-block-type="5" id="block-6735a6ae2178770cbb51"><div class="sqs-block-content" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1648492099690_414">















  

    
  
    <div class="image-block-outer-wrapper layout-caption-below design-layout-inline combination-animation-fade-in individual-animation-none individual-text-animation-none sqs-narrow-width animation-loaded" data-test="image-block-inline-outer-wrapper" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1648492099690_413">

Comment: <figure class="
              sqs-block-image-figure
              intrinsic
            " style="max-width:100%;" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1648492099690_412">
          
        
        

        
          
            <button class="
                  sqs-block-image-button
                  lightbox
                  
          
        
                " data-description="" data-lightbox-theme="dark" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1648492099690_411">
              <span class="v6-visually-hidden">View fullsize</span>

Comment: <div class="image-block-wrapper" data-animation-role="image" data-animation-override="" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1648492099690_410">
            <div class="sqs-image-shape-container-element
              
          
        
              has-aspect-ratio
            " style="
                position: relative;
                
                  padding-bottom:56.25%;
                
                overflow: hidden;
              " id="yui_3_17_2_1_1648492099690_409">

Comment: <noscript><img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/6230d1e067d89c6cd2897b99/4f2e4cfd-8442-469f-b539-624748531e32/A+lovely+sunset+in+Killiney.jpg" alt="" /></noscript><img class="thumb-image loaded" data-src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/6230d1e067d89c6cd2897b99/4f2e4cfd-8442-469f-b539-624748531e32/A+lovely+sunset+in+Killiney.jpg" data-image="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/6230d1e067d89c6cd2897b99/4f2e4cfd-8442-469f-b539-624748531e32/A+lovely+sunset+in+Killiney.jpg" data-image-dimensions="4000x2250" data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" alt=""

Comment: data-load="false" data-image-id="623a5b8d46540d5683437bb5" data-type="image" style="left: -61.6531%; top: 0%; width: 223.306%; height: 100%; position: absolute;" data-image-resolution="2500w" src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/6230d1e067d89c6cd2897b99/4f2e4cfd-8442-469f-b539-624748531e32/A+lovely+sunset+in+Killiney.jpg?format=2500w">
            </div>
          </div>
        
            </button>
          
        

        
      
        </figure>
      

    </div>
  


  


</div></div>

Comment: @AHaworth sorry if it's too confusing, but it was quite long to fit in one text box, so I splitted in 5 comments. that's all the code for that single image

Comment: Code must be in your question (which you can edit to add the code) not in a series of comments.